# How to set the default text to DatePicker in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, datepicker

How to set the default text to DatePicker?

I searched in many blogs, all are saying to customize the DatePicker. is it not possible to set the string value to default DatePicker?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set a value for date picker , here is what you need to do

```
private void DatePicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DatePicker picker = sender as DatePicker;
    DateTimeOffset newDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    DateTimeOffset.TryParse("4/17/2013", out newDate);

    if (picker != null)
    {
        picker.Date = newDate;
        picker.MinYear = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i need to set the text "asap" for Datepicker. Kind of Placeholder. can it be possible to map the string "asap" to DatePicker value?

Comment: I dont think so...Why don't you give a label above?

Comment: Ya. its given..but still we have an requirement to display the default string to DatePicker

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two solutions:

1) Overlay your DatePicker With a Button and Display the default content inside the button. Basicaly you need to implement next behaviour:

- When Button is Visible hide DatePicker (By default)
- When User clicks the button show the DatePicker DateSelector Windows
- When User chooses value in DateSelector Hide the Button and Display DatePicker

2) Use Telerik RadDateSelector control. You must implement the same behaviour but it is much easier:

- You have a button with custom content.
- When user clicks the button show RadDateSelector
- When user chooses value in RadDateSelector you just set the content of the button to selected value

I use the second approach in my WP8 app and first approach in my WP8.1 app (just because there is no Telerik RadDateSelector for WP8.1 right now).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. 
But, i just had one doubt,When I tried setting the ValueStringFormat="text", DatePicker is displaying the text.
Is it okay to do like this? because, the purpose of using the ValueStringFormat is different.

Comment: ValueStringFormat is the property which is used when converting the Value property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=VS.95%29.aspx - here is the list of supported formats. I am really surprised if that property understand "text".